# Connecting to Cloud SQL with Private IP gives timeout when trying to connect in Cloud Functions despite successful connectivity test

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, vpc

I am trying to connect to a Cloud SQL instance with Private IP through a Cloud Function which runs all egress traffic through a VPC connector.

I did a connectivity test which gave the following results:

[image]

Then, I deployed a Cloud Function [following the docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions) and run the following code:

```
import sqlalchemy
import os
from google.cloud import storage

# SQLAlchemy==1.4.28
# psycopg2-binary==2.9.2
# google-cloud-storage==2.2.1

def hello_world(request):
    # Remember - storing secrets in plaintext is potentially unsafe. Consider using
    # something like https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/overview to help keep
    # secrets secret.
    db_user = '<DB-USER>'
    db_pass = '<DB-PASSWORD>'
    db_name = 'postgres'
    db_host = '172.16.0.5:5432'

    # Extract port from db_host if present,
    # otherwise use DB_PORT environment variable.
    host_args = db_host.split(":")
    if len(host_args) == 1:
        db_hostname = db_host
        db_port = os.environ["DB_PORT"]
    elif len(host_args) == 2:
        db_hostname, db_port = host_args[0], int(host_args[1])

    print(f"{db_hostname}, {db_port}")
    pool = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        # Equivalent URL:
        # mysql+pymysql://<db_user>:<db_pass>@<db_host>:<db_port>/<db_name>
        sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
            drivername="postgresql+psycopg2",
            username=db_user,  # e.g. "my-database-user"
            password=db_pass,  # e.g. "my-database-password"
            host=db_hostname,  # e.g. "127.0.0.1"
            port=db_port,  # e.g. 5432
            database=db_name,  # e.g. "my-database-name"
        )
    )
    print(f'Created engine : {pool}')
    pool.connect()
    print(f'Done engine : {pool}')

    return 'Ended well', 200
```

However, it is unable to connect to the instance, and the function times out at `pool.connect()`:

[image]

I confirm that the source IP is in line with the expectation of the connectivity test (11.0.0.11).

What could be the reason, or what could I do to find out the actual cause?

Comment: Go ahead, but isn’t that for the proxy?

Comment: The connectivity works from a VM. Now, what about the VPC connector? Are you sure that you use the the correct VPC?

Comment: There is just one, attached to the cloud function, which source is the ip 11.0.0.11. I can confirm that by looking at the egress settings of the function.

Comment: Is your VPC serverless connector located in the [same region & project](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions#configure) as your Cloud Function deployment? You could try passing a DB options dictionary when [creating](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/main/cloud-sql/postgres/sqlalchemy/main.py#L49) an `SQLAlchemy` engine to test longer timeouts as well.

Comment: @ErnestoC It is in the same region. Longer timeouts didn't work. Anything it could be related to that it starts with 11 and not 10?

Comment: Is your VPC serverless connector also in the [same](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-functions#private-ip) VPC network as your CloudSQL instance? I deployed your code in a Function and saw a timeout when connecting to the pool, which was resolved by moving the connector and Postgres instance to the same VPC. If not, please add how your VPC network(s), CloudSQL instance and Cloud Function are structured and configured in relation to each other, as the problem originates from the configuration rather than the code.